# Loading state not effective in the React application (MobX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading, mobx, mobx-react

I am coding a React app that fetches data from WordPress REST API. Everything works fine so far, however, loading indicator does not show up. I use MobX for state management. I have a loadingInitial observable. Whenever I start my action, I set this observable true to get into loading state. After the action does necessary operations, I reset loadingInitial to false. So I expect to see loading screen while fetching posts. But I see blank page while the daha is loading.

Here are the code for the action:

```js
    @action loadAnecdotes = async (page: number, year: number, order: string) => {
        this.loadingInitial = true
        try {
            const anecdotesHeaders = year === 0 ? await agent.AnecdotesHeaders.list() : await agent.AnecdotesHeaders.listByYear(year)
            const maxPages = anecdotesHeaders['x-wp-totalpages']
            
            if (page <= maxPages) {
                const anecdotes = year === 0 ? await agent.Anecdotes.list(page, order) : await agent.Anecdotes.listByYear(page, year, order)
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.anecdoteArray = []
                    anecdotes.forEach((anecdote, i) => {
                        this.anecdoteArray[i] = anecdote
                    })
                    this.loadingInitial = false
                })
            } else {
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.loadingInitial = false
                })
            }
            return {anecdoteArray: this.anecdoteArray, maxPages}
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            this.loadingInitial = false
        }
    }
```

Here is my useEffect in the component where I fetch the posts:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        loadAnecdotes(page, year, order).then(result => {
            if (page <= result?.maxPages)
                setArray(a => [...a, ...result?.anecdoteArray!])
            setLoaded(true)
        })
    }, [loadAnecdotes, page, year, order, setLoaded, setArray])
```

Here is the what I call just before the returning the posts:

```js
if (loadingInitial) return <LoadingComponent content='Anecdotes loading...' />
```

As a side note, my component is set as an observer.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you returning something in the loadAnecdotes action?, and then in the component you are calling the function and setting the result in a react state inside the useEffect, that breaks the whole purpose of MobX. You should instead in save the result of the action in a property of the class/store, and in the react component read directly the property

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems loadingInitial is not enough alone. I added a second condition to it, the length of the posts array. If it is 0, show the loading component. And it worked! Just this edit solves the problem:

```js
if (loadingInitial || !array.length) return <LoadingComponent content='Anecdotes loading...' />
```